# SQL Server 2012 missing RowVersion datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I recently restored my database onto a new SQL Server 2012 and notice that all my table columns of `RowVersion` data types have been changed to `binary(8)`

In Management Studio when I design the tables, the drop down for the data types no longer even has a choice for `rowversion`.

I cant find anything from MS  other than old information that says it should still exist, or that it is equivalent to `binary(8)` however `binary(8)` doesn't auto generate a value like `rowversion` or `timestamp`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this but it should be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ALTER COLUMN YourCol rowversion
```

I think it's by design. Conversion to `binary(8)` means that any values generated so far are preserved but in order to carry on auto-generating, you need to convert back to `rowversion` using the above.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I tried that.  It replaces it with timestamp instead of rowversion

Comment: so rowversion appears to be gone - wierd since they said timestamp was obsoleted